# Gitlab runner Container hostname

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When i start a build in gitlab ci (docker executer) its creating container with name "runner-0fa22293-project-174-concurrent-0-postgres"

In this what does "0fa22293-project-174-concurrent-0" represent ?

What is the naming convention used here?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the format is as follows:

```
runner-<token>-project-<project ID>-concurrent-<concurrent job #>
```

- `<token>` is the first 8 characters of the Runner Token for the CI runner that is running the build.
- `<project ID>` is the ID of the project. The is the project ID you'd use during API access too.
- `<concurrent job #>` is the number of this job, for this build. GitLab CI lets you run several jobs in a build concurrently, so if you had 3 of 5 jobs running concurrently you would see `...-concurrent-0`, `...-concurrent-1`, `...-concurrent-2`

Comment: its not <commit hash> . its the first 8 characters of the sha hash of the Runner Token which is used to build.