# Correlate a gitlab ci run to its runner

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a setup where docker containers run gitlab runners, which connects to my gitlab instance. At the moment we have a problem (error: could not lock config file .git/config: No space left on device), which happens some of the time. The fact that it does not happen all the time, implies there is something wrong with a specific runner. But how can I know which runner has executed a run?

In the logging it says something like `Running on c8eda3bbebb9...`, but I cannot correlate that hash to any of the runners in my runner overview.

I have added debug info in my script, but this error occurs before the script. So the hash is the only thing to go on.

Any idea what that hash means and how to connect it to a specific runner instance? Or another way to detect the running instance?

Comment: Do you have access to the admin area? The builds list at `/admin/builds` will tell you which runner ran each build.

Also, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40097451/4245525) describes the format of the docker container names when running Gitlab CI with the docker executor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, using the description field of the gitlab runner.

I added the hostname and the docker id of the environment to the description of the runner. Now I could lookup a failing build, look at it's runner ID in the right-hand sidebar, and then lookup that runner in the runners overview, and see it's hostname there.